# Как сложить количество символов

Tags: javascript

Экспериментирую со строками и встрял в тупик как вывести в консоль не сам символ, а количество (подсчет) его повторений. Сейчас консоль выводит `d, m, s, f`, а как вывести `3, 3, 3, 2`? Пробовал свойство `length`, но тогда выводит 1.

```js
function countFig(str) {
  let figure = '';
  let figureCount = 0;
  let result = '';

  for (const item of str) {
    if (figure === item) {
      result += `${figure}${figureCount}`;
    }

    figure = item;

    figureCount = item.length //вот здесь я не понимаю как подсчитать количество повторяющихся символов

  }
  return result;
}

console.log(countFig('dddmmmsssff'));
```

Comment: "Прикрепляю скрин для примера" - кому нужен Ваш "скрин"? Прикрепляйте код.

Comment: Прикрепил код, скрин убрал

Comment: И что? Придумать, как Вы вызываете эту функцию и что она дoлжна делать, мы должны сами?

Comment: Дописал функцию, мне не понятно как найти figureCount

Comment: функция должна возвращать "d3m3s3f2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только поменяв выделеную строчку не получится. В результат нужно добавлять строку, только если символ поменялся. Например так:

```js
function countFig(str) {
  if (str.length === 0) {
    return '';
  }

  let result = '';

  let prev = str[0];
  let count = 1;

  // Перебираем все символы, кроме первого. Он уже учтен в prev
  for (const curr of str.slice(1)) {
    // Если предыдущий и текущий символы отличаются,
    // то добавляем в результат и сбрасываем счетчик
    // иначе инкрементируем счетчик
    if (prev !== curr) {
      result += `${prev}${count}`;
      count = 1;
    } else {
      count++;
    }

    prev = curr;
  }

  // последний символ не будет учтен в цикле, исправляем это
  result += `${prev}${count}`;

  return result;
}

console.log(countFig('dddmmmsssff'));
```

Можно также решить с помощью HashMap. Igor уже показал как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function countFig(str) {
  const lookup = {};
  for (const item of str) {
    lookup[item] = (lookup[item] || 0) + 1;
  }
  return Object.keys(lookup).map(k => k + lookup[k]).join('');
}

console.log(countFig('dddmmmsssff'));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Igor Это для меня новое решение, благодарю за ответ

Comment: @Victor Пожалуйста. Решение, возможно, неправильное, если надо считать только одинаковые символы подряд. Этот посчитает все буквы `d` в строке, где бы они не находились.